# Anytime function call when pressing a key C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make my program in c++ show a message (like a quick guide, using `cout<<"Instructions";`) every time h is pressed, but keeping the sequence?

Example:

```
#include <everything>
using namespace std;
int main{
    {Event 1}
    {Event 2}
    {Event 3}
}


~Program running~
(Event 1) runs
*user presses h*
*shows help automatically*
(event 2) runs
(event 3) runs
exit
```

I have searched but couldn't find how to do it in c++.

Comment: What system are you on? What compiler are you using? Do you have access to C++11 features, like the new threading library?

Comment: A good start would be to google event handling in C++. There should be sources to give you a general idea there. After that you may want to look up SFML or SDL libraries. They help abstract hardware events so your job is easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on any Linux/Unix like systems you can handle the 'h' key-press with a signal interrupt handler in you main program, something like:

```
#include <csignal>
// ...
void signalHandler( int signum ) {
    cout << "Here your help...\n";
}
int main() {
    // kick off your other thread to run select()...
    signal(USER1, signalHandler);
    // ...
}
```

and then run in the other thread you kicked off, run code that calls `select()` on `stdin` and then (when there's input) `read()` to get the charater that's been entered, if it's `h` then send the `USER1` signal to your main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Because I recently joined SO and don't have enough reputation to comment on existing answers, I have to start a new answer.

I agree with @paul-evans' answer, and would like to share the slides if you want to learn the basics of OS process management and signal handling: https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~wmm24/cs283/lectures/procmgt.ppt, which is based on Chapter 8 of the classic CSAPP (Computer Systems A Programmer's Prespective)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for a in-game menu. The user presses the ESC button to bring the menu up, and F8 to exit the game

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

#define KB_UP 72
#define KB_DOWN 80
#define KB_LEFT 75
#define KB_RIGHT 77
#define KB_ESCAPE 27
#define KB_F8 66

void gamemenu()
{
    cout<<"  \n";
    cout<<"[1] Resume Game  \n";
    cout<<"[2] Save Game  \n";
    cout<<"[3] Exit Game  \n";
}

int main()
{
   int KB_code=0;

   cout<<"Game menu 0.01 beta\n\n";
   cout<<"press F8 to Exit\n";
   cout<<"press ESC for Game menu \n";

   while(KB_code != KB_F8 )
   { 
     if (kbhit())
      {
            KB_code = getch();
            //cout<<"KB_code = "<<KB_code<<"\n";

            switch (KB_code)
            {

                case KB_ESCAPE:

                    gamemenu();

                break;

                case KB_LEFT:
                           //Do something
                break;

                case KB_RIGHT:
                           //Do something                     
                break;

                case KB_UP:
                           //Do something                     
                break;

                case KB_DOWN:
                           //Do something                     
                break;

            }        

      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Game menu 0.01 beta

press F8 to Exit
press ESC for Game menu

[1] Resume Game
[2] Save Game
[3] Exit Game
```